# Why won't the BufferedReader read past the first line of the .csv?

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

I am trying to skip past the first row of my .csv file, which is what my first if statement should be solving, then iterate through the .csv file and create new Call objects and add them to the Array called callList. Instead of reading past the first line, it only reads the first line, then gives me a `NullPointerException`. Any idea? Why this is happening?

```
public static void parseCalls(String fileName) {

    int firstRow = 1;
    int counter = firstRow;
    String line = "";

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                if(counter == firstRow) { //should skip first row
                    br.readLine();
                }
                // use comma as separator
                String[] splitCalls = line.split(",");
                callList.add(new Call(splitCalls[6], splitCalls[9], splitCalls[25], splitCalls[17]));
                counter++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        parseCalls("test.csv");
}
```

My stack trace is:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at CallAnalyzer.parseCalls(CallAnalyzer.java:95)
    at CallAnalyzer.main(CallAnalyzer.java:323)`

where each error occurs when I call `parseCalls()`.

Comment: Please take the [tour]

Comment: Why all the boilerplate? `Files.lines(...).skip(1).map(line -> line.split(","))` etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all like Boris the Spider said in the comment you can use `Files.lines(...).skip(1).map(line -> line.split(","))` But also in your code in your first if you read the line but do not assign it to your line variable. Therefore later in your code you try to split contents of variable line that contains your first line. You did not provide the stacktrace but I bet your `NullPointerException` occurrs on `splitCalls[6]` while your splitCalls doesn't have 6th element because you split the wrong line. If you want to stay with your code then do something like this:

```
public static void parseCalls(String fileName) {

    int firstRow = 1;
    int counter = firstRow;
    String line = "";

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                if(counter == firstRow) { //should skip first row
                    counter++;
                    continue;
                }
                // use comma as separator
                String[] splitCalls = line.split(",");
                callList.add(new Call(splitCalls[6], splitCalls[9], splitCalls[25], splitCalls[17]));
                counter++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Or better yet:

```
public static void parseCalls(String fileName) {

    boolean firstRow = true;
    String line = "";

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                if(firstRow) { //should skip first row
                    firstRow = false;
                    continue;
                }
                // use comma as separator
                String[] splitCalls = line.split(",");
                callList.add(new Call(splitCalls[6], splitCalls[9], splitCalls[25], splitCalls[17]));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! For some reason, the function is still only reading the first line. I have added print statements and determined that it breaks out of the while loop when i try to add new Calls to the callList. The callList is a static Array<Call> so it should be able to be manipulated within the class right?

Comment: Add the stacktrace to your problem description, that should help. Is it still NullPointerException you get?

Comment: Yes, as I suspected your `splitCalls` array doesn't have 6th element. so when you try to access it it fails with this exception. Either your csv file is not valid or split goes wrong for some other reason. In general after you split the String you should check how many elements you got in the array. Because if you only got say 3 elements by try to access 5th you will fail with this exception. Debug your code and check how many elements are in your array. In general you really should check it in the code before accessing it.

Comment: You can make a `GetElement` helper function that checks whether the requested index is in range, and returns null if it isn't, and the element if it is...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(counter == firstRow) { //should skip first row
    br.readLine();
}
```

Here you are not assigning the result of `readLine()` to the variable `line`. But it would be even better to bring this out of the loop, and read a line before going into the loop. That way you don't have to check for the first line every time a line is read.

```
String[] splitCalls = line.split(",");
callList.add(new Call(splitCalls[6], splitCalls[9], splitCalls[25], splitCalls[17]));
```

Here you should really check the length of `splitCalls[]` first before accessing any elements. The content of a csv file should never be trusted, and some lines could have only 3 columns for example, which throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (but the reason you get this now is because `line` still contains the first line of your file and probably contains less items).

So you would have something like:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

    br.readLine();

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
            String[] splitCalls = line.split(",");
            // check length of array here, if ok:
            callList.add(new Call(splitCalls[6], splitCalls[9], splitCalls[25], splitCalls[17]));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call

```
line = br.readLine();
```

in the if branch, and later test for line != null before splitting. Else the first line is still stored in line.

And it doesn't read just one line on my system.

I guess your first line is some comment or headline, don't containing enough commas to split the string, and therefore splitCalls[6] triggers the exeption, then, of course, no further line is read.